# How to change the font to 'Arial Narrow' for Python matplotlib on figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I want to change my font for matplotlib texts on figures to Arial Narrow, but unfortunately I always get the following error message:

```
py:1316: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Arial Narrow'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
```

I also wrote the following in my code, even though I use it, it does not work:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial Narrow'
```

I use Spyder Python 3.6 in Anaconda on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you checked if Arial Narrow is in the list of matplotlib's readable font in your environment?  (Here is indicated how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27564040/5405298)

Comment: Thanks! I have checked and it does NOT contain 'Arial Narrow'. How can I install it?

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37921026/5405298. The idea is to force matplotlib to rebuild the font list by deleting a file in the `.matplotlibrc` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Arial Narrow is just a compressed Arial, so if you use this, it should work, provided you have it installed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'
plt.rcParams['font.stretch'] = 'condensed'
```