# Matplotlib throws warning message because of findfont - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I want to plot a basic graph, basically consisting of two lists of the form
x = [1,2,3,...,d], y = [y1,y2,...,yd].
after using_ `pyplot.plot(x,y)` I get a huge amount of warning messages referring to **findfont errors** (see below..)

I just installed matplotlib. All the threads I could find refer to changing fonts manually and having warning messages popping up. I did not do anything like that. I just installed the package and that is it.

I am using pycharm, python 3.6 and windows for programming.

```
DEBUG  findfont: Matching :family=sans-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0.
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'cmex10' (cmex10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeOneSym' (STIXSizOneSymReg.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'cmb10' (cmb10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans' (DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 0.33499999999999996
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXNonUnicode' (STIXNonUniBolIta.ttf) italic normal bold normal>) = 11.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' (DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Serif' (DejaVuSerif.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'cmr10' (cmr10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXGeneral' (STIXGeneralItalic.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXGeneral' (STIXGeneralBol.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeTwoSym' (STIXSizTwoSymBol.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeOneSym' (STIXSizOneSymBol.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Serif' (DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf) italic normal bold normal>) = 11.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXGeneral' (STIXGeneral.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' (DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf) oblique normal bold normal>) = 11.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' (DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf) oblique normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeFourSym' (STIXSizFourSymBol.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXNonUnicode' (STIXNonUniIta.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Serif' (DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'cmsy10' (cmsy10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXNonUnicode' (STIXNonUni.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeFourSym' (STIXSizFourSymReg.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeThreeSym' (STIXSizThreeSymBol.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Serif' (DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeFiveSym' (STIXSizFiveSymReg.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'cmss10' (cmss10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'cmmi10' (cmmi10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' (DejaVuSansMono.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'cmtt10' (cmtt10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeTwoSym' (STIXSizTwoSymReg.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXNonUnicode' (STIXNonUniBol.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Display' (DejaVuSansDisplay.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Serif Display' (DejaVuSerifDisplay.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeThreeSym' (STIXSizThreeSymReg.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans' (DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf) oblique normal 400 normal>) = 1.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans' (DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf) oblique normal bold normal>) = 1.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'STIXGeneral' (STIXGeneralBolIta.ttf) italic normal bold normal>) = 11.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans' (DejaVuSans.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 0.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Franklin Gothic Book' (FRABK.TTF) normal normal book normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Microsoft Yi Baiti' (msyi.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Matura MT Script Capitals' (MATURASC.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Wide Latin' (LATINWD.TTF) normal normal 400 expanded>) = 10.25
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Gigi' (GIGI.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Georgia' (georgiab.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Microsoft Tai Le' (taile.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Wingdings 3' (WINGDNG3.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Copperplate Gothic Bold' (COPRGTB.TTF) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Palatino Linotype' (palabi.ttf) italic normal bold normal>) = 11.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Segoe UI' (segoeuii.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Arial Rounded MT Bold' (ARLRDBD.TTF) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Verdana' (verdanai.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 4.6863636363636365
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Microsoft Himalaya' (himalaya.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Gloucester MT Extra Condensed' (GLECB.TTF) normal normal 400 condensed>) = 10.25
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Palatino Linotype' (palab.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Playbill' (PLAYBILL.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Rage Italic' (RAGE.TTF) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Perpetua' (PERI____.TTF) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Constantia' (constani.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Segoe UI Emoji' (seguiemj.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'KaiTi' (simkai.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Tw Cen MT Condensed' (TCCM____.TTF) normal normal 400 condensed>) = 10.25
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Corbel' (corbel.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Nirmala UI' (Nirmala.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Baskerville Old Face' (BASKVILL.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Wingdings' (wingding.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Segoe UI' (segoeui.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Arial' (ariblk.ttf) normal normal black normal>) = 6.888636363636364
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Courier New' (cour.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Courier New' (couri.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Bookshelf Symbol 7' (BSSYM7.TTF) normal normal book normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Microsoft Uighur' (MSUIGHUB.TTF) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Lucida Fax' (LFAXDI.TTF) italic normal demibold normal>) = 11.24
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Garamond' (GARA.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Consolas' (consolai.ttf) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Lucida Sans Typewriter' (LTYPE.TTF) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Perpetua Titling MT' (PERTIBD.TTF) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Britannic Bold' (BRITANIC.TTF) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Lucida Calligraphy' (LCALLIG.TTF) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Lucida Bright' (LBRITE.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Ebrima' (ebrima.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Calisto MT' (CALIST.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Roboto' (Roboto-Bold.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Gadugi' (gadugi.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Colonna MT' (COLONNA.TTF) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Nirmala UI' (NirmalaS.ttf) normal normal light normal>) = 10.24
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Microsoft Tai Le' (taileb.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Bodoni MT' (BOD_CBI.TTF) italic normal bold condensed>) = 11.535
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Berlin Sans FB' (BRLNSB.TTF) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Gill Sans MT' (GILI____.TTF) italic normal 400 normal>) = 11.05
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Rockwell' (ROCKBI.TTF) italic normal bold normal>) = 11.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Gill Sans MT' (GILB____.TTF) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
DEBUG  findfont: score(<Font 'Constantia' (constanb.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335
[...............]
DEBUG  findfont: Matching :family=sans-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0 to DejaVu Sans ('C:\\Users\\chris\\PycharmProjects\\DeepNN-Solver\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\mpl-data\\fonts\\ttf\\DejaVuSans.ttf') with score of 0.050000.
```

Comment: You are in some kind of debug mode. Those lines are basically just telling you what matplotlib does internally when rendering text; it should only be exposed to the user in case logging is activated. Check for any place where you may have some debugging/logging mode enabled and turn it off.

Comment: Try the solution listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920935/matplotlib-cant-find-font

Comment: As I said I did not install any new fonts bro. Logging is activated. That solved the "issue".

Comment: Thanks I disabled logging after my programme computed and only the plots are left to process. Using `logging.disable(sys.maxsize)` at this point solved the issue.

Comment: it's a "bug": https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14523

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just as an alternative solution, you can disable the matplotlib font manager logger.

```
logging.getLogger('matplotlib.font_manager').disabled = True
```

Or you can just suppress the DEBUG messages but not the others from that logger.

```
logging.getLogger('matplotlib.font_manager').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Is there any way to add this solution to global settings?

Comment: Is there a way to this with entirety of matplotlib? simply removing .font_manager does not work.

Comment: Great, this is simple and effective.

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same issue. I realized I had enabled DEBUG mode in logging, but I actually wanted to enable it for debugging my own script (not matplotlib). The fix is to assign your logger a unique name and enable DEBUG mode there instead.

Code before:

```py
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Fix:

```py
log = logging.getLogger('UNIQUE_NAME_HERE')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

And better yet, use a dynamic name that uses the name of the current module (if your code is in a module):

```py
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

The above method is recommended and described in more detail here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Alternatively, you could instead set the logging level to something other than DEBUG (e.g. `log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`).